# Assembly , no such instruction popl?

Tags: c, gcc, assembly, x86, inline-assembly

I have a code in C where the main tak is written in Assembly. The idea of the programm is to for example when x = abc def ,and y = a it deletes the word where at least one letter is the same and writes words without the same letters so it would write def. I have wrotten a code, but it gives error like :

- prog.c:10: Error: no such instruction: `addl $112,%esp'
- prog.c:12: Error: no such instruction: `xorl %eax,%eax'
- prog.c:13: Error: no such instruction: `popl %ebx'
- prog.c:16: Error: no such instruction: `popl %esi'

Here is the code :

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(){
    char *x = "asbc4a2bab ";
    char *y = "ab";
    char bufor[100];
asm volatile (
    ".intel_syntax noprefix;"
    "mov ecx,%0;"
    "push ecx;" //wrzuca na stos
    "mov ecx,%1;"
    "mov eax,%2;"
    "call zadanie1;"
    "jmp wyjscie;"
    "zadanie1:"
    "push ebp;" //wrzucamy ebp na stos

    "push eax;"
    "push ecx;" //ecx zliczanie
    "push edi;" //edi destination
    "mov ebp,esp;" //do ebp adres stosu

    "mov esi,[ebp+20];" //esi bezposrednio do x
    "mov edi,[ebp+4];" //edi adres y
    "mov ebx,[ebp+8];"//ebx bufor
    "mov eax,0;"//eax to false
    "push eax;"
    "push esi;"
    "push eax;"
    "etykieta_x:"

    "mov eax,[esp+8];"
    "cmp eax,0;"
    "je etykieta_y;"
    "mov [esp+4],esi;"
    "mov eax,0;"
    "mov [esp+8],eax;"
    //"mov [esp+4],esi;"
        "etykieta_y:"

            "mov eax,[edi];"
            "cmp eax,'\0';" //porownoje eax z koncem
            "je koniec_etykiety_x;"
            "add edi,1;"//zwiekszamy petle
            "cmp eax,[esi];"//porownoje y i x
            "jne etykieta_y;"//wrocimy do etykiety y jesli nie sa rowne
            "ustaw_flage:"
                "pop eax;"
                "mov eax,1;" //ustawia flage
                "push eax;"

        "koniec_etykiety_x:"
        "pop eax;"
        "cmp eax,1;"
        "jne iteruj_dalej;"
        "mov eax,0;"
        "push eax;"

        "iteruj_po_znakach:"
            "add esi,1;"
            "mov eax,[esi];"
            "cmp eax,'\0';"
            "je koniec;"
            "cmp eax,' ';"
            "je spacja_wykryta;"
            "jmp etykieta_x;"

            "spacja_wykryta:"
                "mov eax,1;"
                "mov [esp+8],eax;"
                "jmp iteruj_po_znakach;"



        "iteruj_dalej:"
            "mov eax,0;"
            "push eax;"
            "add esi,1;"//zwiekszamy adres
            "mov eax,[esi];"//pobieramhy nast zznak
            "cmp eax,'\0';"
            "je zapisz_do_bufora;"
            "cmp eax,' ';"
            "je spacja_wykryta_2;"

                "mov eax,[esp+8];"
                "cmp eax,0;"
                "je etykieta_x;"
                "jmp zapisz_do_bufora;"

            "spacja_wykryta_2:"
            "mov eax,1;"
            "mov [esp+8],eax;"
            "jmp iteruj_dalej;"


            "zapisz_do_bufora:"
                "mov eax,[esp+4];"

                "interuj_po_slowie:"
                    "mov edx,[eax];"
                    "cmp edx,' ';"
                    "je etykieta_x;"
                    "cmp edx, '\0';"
                    "je etykieta_x;"

                    "mov [ebx],edx;"
                    "add eax,1;"
                    "add ebx,1;"
                    "jmp iteruj_po_slowie;"

    "koniec:"
    "pop edi;" //zdejmuje ze stosu
    "pop ecx;"
    "pop eax;"
    "pop ebp;"
    "ret;" //wyjdzie z funkcji
    "wyjscie:"
    ".att_syntax_prefix;"
    :
    :"r"(x), "r"(y), "r"(bufor)
    :"eax", "ecx"
    );
    return 0;
}
```

and here is the ideone link : http://ideone.com/wHFeDK
Someone know what may be wrong ? Thanks for help.

Comment: For what platform and compiler?

Comment: You realize there is already a practically identical question open?

Comment: It should be done for linux , nasm

Answer (score 1):

It's a horrible hack to manually switch syntax mode in inline asm and it might not work if you have any argument substitutions. The correct way is to use `-masm=intel` if you want intel syntax.

That said, your problem is that you have a typo in the directive where you wanted to restore the mode: you have `.att_syntax_prefix` instead of `.att_syntax prefix` (notice you don't need another underscore before `prefix`).

Also, the `'\0'` won't work, you should just use `0`.

And, you have a typo: `interuj_po_slowie` vs `iteruj_po_slowie`.

PS: Stackoverflow is an english language forum, please post code in english, and comment it properly.